# Do complex sentences always need a conjunction?

Tags: terminology, conjunctions, syntactic-analysis, complex-sentences

> "At her age, Minggay Awok's only companions were a few charcoal black chickens."

Because of "At her age," does this make the sentence complex, or is it still a simple sentence? I do know complex sentences are supposed to have conjunctions, but this phrase clearly cannot stand on its own.

Comment: What is true is that complex sentences always need a few charcoal black chickens.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Although it is an adjunct in the clause and is a prepositional phrase, most traditional grammarians would not regard *at her age* as a clause at all: it has no verb, no expressed subject so on and so forth. It would seem to have the same status as *in the morning*, or *at the end of the day*

Comment: Only adverbial clauses are introduced by a conjunction, as a rule. Noun clauses and adjectival clauses use complementizers and/or special syntax to distinguish them. And simply putting two sentences together (the way a semicolon does) usually does put one in some adverbial relation with the other, but which one is not clear out of context. So that's simply a matter of ambiguity, because if it is deleted, it's not clear how to recover it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A complex sentence has more than one clause, and a clause requires a subject and verb.  "At her age" is a prepositional phrase, which doesn't contain a verb, so your sentence remains simple.

Conjunctions may be omitted.  Punctuation may take their place:

> Minggay Awok was lonely; her only companions were a few charcoal black
>   chickens.
>   His business judgment was soon proved correct:  the company went bankrupt three months later.

Or a conjunction may be [elided]

> She's the one [that] I've always loved.

Comment: Semicolons are full stops. A sentence with a semicolon between clauses is really two sentences, stuck together only in writing. In speech you can't tell the difference between a semicolon and a period.

Comment: Semicolons are not full stops.  For instance, they may be used to separate conjoined clauses that themselves contain commas.

Comment: @deadrat John's point is that they are two separate grammatically complete strings. There is no grammatical relationship that holds the two parts together. I had a different query though, I was wondering why you classed *that* as a conjunction?

Comment: My point is that they're not separate, and that a semicolon has been substituted for "and."  I was taught as a lad that the "that" in that sentence was called a "relative conjunction."  Was that bad pedagogy?  I still remember the happy hours I spent diagramming sentences with my quill pen.

Comment: You could just as well use a dash instead of semicolon in the first example - [but ;] as @John says, no-one would recognise *either* in speech. Which is after all the "real" *language* that written forms attempt to represent. Are we going to have two different definitions of what constitutes "a sentence" (as opposed to "**two** sentences") dependent on whether it's a spoken or a written context? I dunno, maybe "sentence" doesn't really *mean* anything particular in speech.

Comment: It just occurs to me that using ["gesture syntax"](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/Y09-1002) you could "implement/convey" my **[but]** above with a shrug, or by upturning a palm (or maybe a head-tilt?).

Answer (score 2):

I believe complex sentences don't always need a conjunction.  For example, the sentence which precedes this one is conjunctionless yet complex.

Comment: Does your belief imply there might be multiple definitions of "complex sentence", and that expressing it thusly illustrates your acceptance of a definition that includes your example? I assume you mean your example contains the main clause *complex sentences don't always need a conjunction*, so by implication *I believe* is the dependent clause. I'm not much into terminology, so I don't know - but is it really true that the highlighted words in ***I think** you know* are axiomatically classified as a subordinate/dependent clause?

Comment: (I kinda had to highlight like that because of the context - otherwise obviously I'd have written *I think **you** know!* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Which one? The first sentence of the first comment was slightly "whimsical" (but was nevertheless asked in a genuine spirit of enquiry). And as I admitted, I *really* don't know whether it would be considered correct to classify ***I think*** as a subordinate/dependent clause in my example. My second comment (also slightly whimsical! :) was nevertheless "pertinent/relevant/true" - I do actually suppose ***you*** know whether that classification is normal/correct, even if ***I*** don't.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I'm still at sea.  I'll try to clarify what I meant.  Mostly, I don't think what sentences are classified as complex is a serious issue.  It's just arbitrary terminology.  Who cares?  For my answer, I made up an example that I thought people who use the term "complex sentence" would say was complex, but which had no apparent conjunctions in it.  I thought that was the easiest way to settle the issue.  *I* don't care whether my example is actually complex, if that really even means anything.  (cont.)

Comment: (cont.)  The only interesting issue that might be related is Ross's theory that some sentence-internal clauses may lose their sentential status due to reduction transformations -- tree-pruning is Ross's term.  That issue is discussed in McCawley's **TSPE**.

Comment: oic. Well thanks for taking the trouble to clarify things for me, anyway. I'm also not too interested in terminology, or questions like *What exactly is a "complex sentence"?* But your fellow linguist John Lawler was kind enough to provide me with his now-redundant "spare copy" of TSPE a few years ago, and I *am* still interested in dipping into that on a regular basis, so I'll check out "Ross, tree-pruning". And per my last comment under @deadrat's answer, I might well be moved to ask on SO Linguistics how relevant the term "sentence" (as opposed to "sentential"?) really is in this context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That question might lead to an interesting discussion.

Comment: We shall see - I've just posted [Is “sentence” a useful and/or clearly-defined term in linguistics?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12859/is-sentence-a-useful-and-or-clearly-defined-term-in-linguistics) over on Linguistics.